# Separate NYA cables vs multi-core NYM cable for lighting circuits

Tags: electrical, cable-management

I am in Indonesia and electrical installations are haphazard and dangerous, so I will start off by saying there is not really a lot of point in trying to reference a national standard here.

Also no light switches are grounded, but plug sockets have grounding but it's rarely connected.

So, thinking about a lighting circuit using 1-way switches, what are the relative merits of using single NYA cables compared to NYM

Edit: cable will use conduit and junction boxes.

NYA:

[image]

2-core NYM:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nya in your photo is single conductor in most other parts of the world it requires a conduit for protection of the conductors.
Nym in your photo has 2 conductors with an outer protective covering so no conduit is needed for internal wiring.
From what I can see this would be the difference.

Edit: since adding the job will be in conduit with junction boxes the nya is the way to go  it will pull easier and cost less than nym

Comment: Coming from the US, I'd suggest the NYM cable, but, as the OP noted in his question Indonesia seems to be the "wild, wild west" when it comes to electrical safety requirements, it's probably mostly down to cost as to which to choose.

Comment: @freeman I fully agree if not in conduit I would also use nym.

Comment: I should have said in my OP but conduit is fairly commonly used.

Comment: also differences I can see:

NYA - could use a different colour for the cable to and from the switch? NYM - more physical protection. NYA - can route the live and neutral wire separately possibly saving cable

Comment: Thelawnet if in conduit nym would be better protected but usually much more expensive in conduit.  Multiple circuits can be run in conduit.  In my location residential rarely uses conduit except for the main service feeder. Commercial and heavy industrial almost exclusively conduit. Since you have added that you will be using conduit and junction boxes nym has no advantage it is actually harder to pull in conduit.

Comment: For 3x2.5 the cost is about 12% higher for nym vs nya. For 2x1.5 it's about 47% more. So I was thinking to use the nym for the plug sockets because it seems somehow neater, but I haven't decided for the light switches. Is it usual to use different colours to distinguish between the live cable into a switch and the one out of it?

Comment: In my area we do have rules (you said you did not want the rules). If you take a hot wire from a light fixture or receptacle to a switch the hot to the switch is the normally white so it is always hot (white is usually neutral here but this keeps the switched hot going back to the light from being confused as a neutral it could be confused if white and the switch off) the switch turns on and off the power on the black. This is called a switch leg. But in conduit we would normally use a black for the power and a red for the switched power to the light (most electronic controls here use red swit